# Access query- validating data between two columns

Tags: validation, ms-access

I have a table that have a Certificate # column and a Plan-Phase column, one Certificate # has multiple plan-phase values for example:

Cert #-------Plan-Phase

123----------1

123----------2

123----------4

222----------1

222----------2

333 ---------- 3

I need to run a query that checks that every cert # has a plan-Phase "1" record, and return the cert # that do not have plan-Phase 1.

So my example will return cert # "333" because it has no Plan-Phase "1".
I am working in access, I tried counting, and other combination of queries but i was unable to achieve my goal.

I bet it is pretty simple and I am just missing something.

Thank you,
Idan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use subqueries with an outer join to find what you are looking for. Something like this:

```
SELECT qOther.* 
FROM 
(SELECT CertNo
FROM MyTable
WHERE PlanPhase <> 1) qOther
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT CertNo
FROM MyTable
WHERE PlanPhase = 1) qOne
ON qOther.CertNo = qOne.CertNo
WHERE qOne.CertNo IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you, I build two queries, one that list the all cert# and one that list only the ones with phase 1, and did an unmatching query.

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested this in Oracle (I don't have Access installed at the moment), but it should also work in Access as there's no Oracle-specific code:

```
SELECT cert#
FROM certNo
WHERE cert# NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT cert#
     FROM certNo
     WHERE plan-phase = 1);
```

I have tested this against your example data. What this query does is create a set of certificate numbers that has a plan-phase 1 associated with it (using the sub-query), then selects all cert# entries that aren't part of that set, ie: Have no phase 1.

Also, it's worth noting that `certNo` is to be replaced with whatever name your table is.